# Capture Webcam Video within Buddypress (and BuddyPress Media)

Tags: buddypress, videos

Has anyone had experience capturing video from a webcam and adding it to a users album inside of BuddyPress and BuddyPress Media? BuddyPress Media isn't necessary if there's a better solution

BP Media has a premium FFMPEG add-on for converting video which I think will be needed if this is possible; but I have no real experience with hosting, recording, and converting video on a custom site i.e. not within Vimeo or YouTube

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm from the team that developes BuddyPress Media.

Till now, capturing a video involved expensive (in various ways) setups. It depended on flash and silverlight which could reach the hardware (mic and webcam) . Html5 is the way to go, now. However, the support isn't wide enough. This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386675/video-capture-in-html-5.

If you do wish to develop such a solution, do get in touch with us at rtCamp http://rtcamp.com/contact